# unable to install python-flask

Tags: python, flask

when i install python flask the error shows

pip install python-flask
Collecting python-flask
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-flask (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-flask

Comment: This looks frustrating!  Could you give us a bit more information about your set-up? What OS are you using? (e.g. Windows/MacOS/Linux) What version of python? Are you just running this in the command line or is it in a virtual environment or anything? Also, have you tried searching for that error message to see what solutions other people found (and if they work for you or not)? We can hopefully help you more quickly if you can help us narrow down what might be the problem 

Comment: OS windows 10, python version 3.7.4, Running in command line, found in google try to install pip install Flask, even I tried with pip install Flask then still the problem remain same.

Answer (score 3):

**try to install it with:**

```
pip install Flask
```

Comment: Yes, tried with this command. but didn't work

Comment: Do u use this : `python -m pip install flask`   ?

Comment: yes, its say requirement already satisfied

Comment: copy below program to test it :` from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run() `  Now, run the program using  ` python hello.py `

Comment: Error: from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Comment: do u use virtualenv ? try : `pip uninstall flask && python -m pip install flask`